# How to convert this bit of CSS code into SCCS?

Tags: css, sass

I have this css code:

```
.can-toggle *,
  .can-toggle *:before,
  .can-toggle *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

and I want to convert it into scss but I don't know how to.

Comment: https://beautifytools.com/css-to-scss-converter.php

Comment: `:before` is CSS 2.1 syntax. Use `::before` (CSS 3) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [parent selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector) like this:

```
.can-toggle * {
   &, &:before, &:after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
   }
}
```

Comment: :before is CSS 2.1 syntax. Use ::before (CSS 3) instead.

Comment: @connexo it depends on the  browser compatibility you need.

Comment: In this case, not. [`box-sizing`](https://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing) is already CSS 3, and won't do anything in browsers not supporting CSS 3 except IE 8 - `::before` support see https://caniuse.com/css-gencontent.